# TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null when Firebase is removed from app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

My react app runs on Firebase Realtime databases, which I want to remove. But, whenever I do that, I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null
Fish.render
src/components/Fish.js:22
  19 |   this.props.addToOrder(this.props.index);
  20 | };
  21 | 
> 22 | render() {
  23 |   const { image, name, price, desc, status } = this.props.details;
  24 |   const isAvailable = status === "available";
  25 |   return (
```

Here's Fish.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { formatPrice } from "../helpers.js";

class Fish extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.addToOrder(this.props.index);
  };

  render() {
    const { image, name, price, desc, status } = this.props.details;
    const isAvailable = status === "available";
    return (
      <li className="menu-fish">
        <img src={image} alt={name} />
        <h3 className="fish-name">
          {name}
          <span className="price">{formatPrice(price)}</span>
        </h3>
        <p>{desc}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} disabled={!isAvailable}>
          {isAvailable ? "Add to Order" : "Sold out !!"}
        </button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
export default Fish;
```

The error pops in when I delete a fish inside the store I have made, with firebase it gets deleted in App.js file. Without it, this error comes. Please help.

```js
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header.js";
import Order from "./Order.js";
import Inventory from "./Inventory.js";
import sampleFishes from "../sample-fishes.js";
import Fish from "./Fish.js";
// import base from "../base.js";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fishes: {},
    order: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const localStorageRef = localStorage.getItem("/cotd");
    if (localStorageRef) {
      this.setState({ order: JSON.parse(localStorageRef) });
    }

    // this.ref = base.syncState(`/cotd/fishes`, {
    //   context: this,
    //   state: "fishes"
    // });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    localStorage.setItem("/cotd", JSON.stringify(this.state.order));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // base.removeBinding(this.ref);
  }

  addFish = fish => {
    // Taking a copy of the fishes
    const fishes = { ...this.state.fishes };
    // Adding out new fish to fishes variable
    fishes[`fish${Date.now()}`] = fish;
    // New fishes object to state
    this.setState({ fishes });
  };

  updateFish = (key, updateFish) => {
    const fishes = { ...this.state.fishes };
    fishes[key] = updateFish;
    this.setState({ fishes });
  };

  deleteFish = key => {
    const fishes = { ...this.state.fishes };
    fishes[key] = null;
    this.setState({ fishes });
  };

  //  Feature Additon - Reset the order
  resetOrder = key => {
    var order = { ...this.state.order };
    delete order[key];
    this.setState({ order });
  };

  loadSampleFishes = () => {
    this.setState({ fishes: sampleFishes });
  };

  addToOrder = key => {
    const order = { ...this.state.order };
    order[key] = order[key] + 1 || 1;
    this.setState({ order });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="catch-of-the-day">
        <div className="menu">
          <Header tagline="Gotta Catch 'em All" />
          <ul className="fishes">
            {Object.keys(this.state.fishes).map(key => (
              <Fish
                key={key}
                index={key}
                details={this.state.fishes[key]}
                addToOrder={this.addToOrder}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <Order
          fishes={this.state.fishes}
          order={this.state.order}
          resetOrder={this.resetOrder}
        />
        <Inventory
          addFish={this.addFish}
          updateFish={this.updateFish}
          loadSampleFishes={this.loadSampleFishes}
          deleteFish={this.deleteFish}
          fishes={this.state.fishes}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The application uses Firebase to presist the state.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because before your variable `image` is  `null` so when it can't render the component: `<img src={image} alt={name} />`

What you should do is put the initial value to `image` instead of `null`

```
const image = this.props.details.image? this.props.details.image : '';
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Hello Tony, though the logic of your answer seems sound enough. It doesn't help in fixing the problem. The error is still there. Anything else you can think of or need to look at the entire codebase then you can ping me here. Thanks for trying. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When u deleted a fish u set the  value of that key to null in the local state , that is passed as a prop to fish component as null. Now your child component only gets the null value for details and {image,description,name}= this.props.details.
All restructured variables recieve null.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem. Any solution you can suggest for the issue?